# Is wstring character is Unicode ? What happens during conversion?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Recent times I am coming across the conversion of UTF-8 encoding to string and vice vera. I understood that UTF-8 encoding is used to hold almost all the characters in the world while using char which is built in data type for string, only ASCII values can be stored.For a character in UTF-8 encoding the number of bytes required in memory is varied from one byte to 4 bytes but for 'char' type it is usually 1 byte.

My question is what happens in conversion from wstring to string or wchar to char ?
Does the characters which require more than one byte is skipped? It seems it depends on implementation but I want to know what is the correct way of doing it.

Also does wchar is required to store unicode characters ? As far as I understood UNICODE characters can be stored in normal string as well. Why should we use wstring or wchar ?

Comment: `char` is not an encoding, but a data-type. And there is no conversion defined, only a plethora of conversion-functions, and you have to pick the appropriate one.

Comment: @Deduplicator : Thanks for correcting the mistake. Do we need wchar/wstring type for UTF-8 encoding ? I understood that we can use normal string or char

Answer (score 4):

Depends how you convert them.
You need to specify the source encoding type and the target encoding type.
`wstring` is not a format, it just defines a data type.

Now usually when one says "Unicode", one means `UTF16` which is what **Microsoft Windows** uses, and that is usuasly what `wstring` contains.

So, the right way to convert from UTF8 to UTF16:

```
     std::string utf8String = "blah blah";

     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
     std::wstring utf16String = convert.from_bytes( utf8String );
```

And the other way around:

```
     std::wstring utf16String = "blah blah";

     std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
     std::string utf16String = convert.to_bytes( utf16String );
```

And to add to the confusion:
When you use `std::string` on a **windows** platform (like when you use a multibyte compilation), It's NOT **UTF8**. They use **ANSI**.
More specifically, the default encoding language your windows is using.

When compiling in Unicode the windows API commands expect these formats:

Command**A** - **multibyte** - `ANSI`
Command**W** - **Unicode** - `UTF16`

Comment: Windows is using UTF16 encoding type by default and it uses wstring datatype for its implemetation . Is that coorect? I am working on some HTTP encoding and decoding where the characters are UTF-8 encoded , so for this implementation should i need to use wstring or string data type is enough

Comment: @vinothkumareswaran yes, when you use "unicode" it's UTF16. Also C#  and Java use UTF16 strings.

Comment: If one says Unicode one means UTF-16? Nowhere but windows. Also, `wstring` is only UTF-16 on windows, it's UTF-32 otherwise.

Comment: @Deduplicator It's what you put into it. Also on windows it could be UTF-32

Comment: ?? It's what you put into it? What do you mean? And a `wstring` on windows that's UTF-32 would be a severe aberration.

Comment: wstring is a type, not a format. You could use it to store GB 18030 , UCS-2 and of course UTF16 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make your source files UTF-8 encoded, set the character encoding to UNICODE in your IDE.
Use std::string and widen them for WindowsAPI calls. 
`std::string somestring = "こんにちは";
WindowsApiW(widen(somestring).c_str());` 
I know it sounds kind of hacky but a more profound explaination of this issue can be found at [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org/#how).

Comment: In Visual Studio all WinApi calls automatically use the wide string version if you set the encoding to Unicode, so you don't need to explicitly end the function with W.

Comment: You are assigning some special characters to std::string, If I put somestring.c_str() directly , the result is undefined. You have used constant string , which I think is stored in data segement , so at conversion time you are making use windows API and converting it to wide string. Is that correct?

Comment: If you'd do somestring.c_str() you'd get a compiler error, because the WindowsAPI uses wide characters for UNICODE (UTF-16). This is just a workaround because Windows does not natively support UTF-8.

Comment: std::string somestring = "こんにちは";
    cout<<"\n"<<somestring.size();

    std::wstring somestring1 = L"こんにちはこんにちは";
    cout<<"\n"<<somestring1.size();

for the first thing I am not getting compiler error , its printing as ????? . Value is 63 in dec